# Using GoDaddy domain with heroku app

Tags: heroku, dns, shared-hosting, forward

I've built a Heroku Application and added a custom domain for it.
I can verify this by running heroku domains on my project while in the terminal, or by using the heroku dashboard; a target DNS has been assigned.

In my GoDaddy Domain Manager, I've added the CNAME for "www" pointing to the heroku application URL. I've followed bunch of tutorials found on the web and yet cannot see my heroku application when typing my url (I've tried prepending http://, http://www,  www)...

Is there anything I might be missing here? Please, I've been trying for long time and I have even called GoDaddy Support but in my country (México) they don't even know what Heroku is...

Any help is MUCH MUCH appreciated

Comment: Can you tell us what the domain name is? It would help to be able to look up the records etc, if not you will need to have a look at what addresses resolve to which IP's/CNAMES etc.

Comment: sure, the domain is www.omnipagos.com, thanks

Comment: The first problem is that you have not updated www.omnipagos.com to be a CNAME. It is currently an A record pointing to (50.63.202.32) that appears to be a host managed by Godaddy (ip-50-63-202-32.ip.secureserver.net.  http://whois.domaintools.com/secureserver.net).

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS configuration is messed up, it seems that you have created a delegation (NS record) on the [www.omnipagos.com](http://www.omnipagos.com) domain to the heroku site, which should be removed. In fact, all records in that domain should be removed for you to be able to create and use a CNAME as per [RFC1912](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1912#section-2.4)

```
dig www.omnipagos.com any

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> www.omnipagos.com any
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 13274
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 4

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.omnipagos.com.     IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.omnipagos.com.  44  IN  A   50.63.202.32
www.omnipagos.com.  60  IN  NS  www.omnipagos-alpha.herokuapp.com.
www.omnipagos.com.  60  IN  NS  ns25.domaincontrol.com.
www.omnipagos.com.  60  IN  NS  ns26.domaincontrol.com.
www.omnipagos.com.  60  IN  SOA ns25.domaincontrol.com. dns.jomax.net. 2017083101 28800 7200 604800 600

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns25.domaincontrol.com. 72193   IN  A   216.69.185.13
ns25.domaincontrol.com. 10595   IN  AAAA    2607:f208:206::d
ns26.domaincontrol.com. 76947   IN  A   208.109.255.13
ns26.domaincontrol.com. 10595   IN  AAAA    2607:f208:302::d
```

Comment: Thanks, it is my first time setting up domain. So should I delete all records and keep the CNAME only ? (pointing to Heroku).
Again, many thanks for the help...

Comment: That is the suggestion based on the limited information available. I would also recommend spending a couple of hours to understand the basics of DNS so that you are certain that this change makes sense.